# How to write a Windows application that doesn't immediately release control to the calling application

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

I am writing a small application (.exe) that does some tasks and then returns an exit status. It is meant to be run regularly from another application (which I have no control over) that uses the status code to determine further action.

It works just fine if I compile and link it as a console app. However, that makes the console window flash briefly on the screen every time it is run, which is a little bit annoying. I tried to make it a Windows app, but the problem then is that Windows releases control to the calling application (or the OS) immediately after start. Thus, any exit status my application generates is returned too late and is never seen by the calling application.

Is there a way to force my app to stay in the foreground, so to speak, and not release control before it actually exits? I tried to force the entry point to be the "main" function instead of "WinMain", but that didn't help.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's necessary to set options in the calling application to prevent the sub-process to start with no console. You can't do it from the called process side. If I'm wrong, I'll be happy to know it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't a question of whether the child "releases control" or not - Windows is a preemptive multitasking operating system, so all processes run at once.  If the parent process waits for the child to exit, it is because the programmer told it to wait for the child to exit.

It isn't easy to make a program wait for console programs but not non-console programs.  The command shell (`cmd.exe`) works this way when run interactively, but there isn't any API that does this as far as I know.  Assuming that it isn't deliberate - which would be very strange in this context - the only explanation I can think of is that the program is running an interactive command shell and feeding in your command via standard input.  That's the wrong thing to do, but I *have* seen people trying to do it that way before.

Presumably you can choose the command line that the parent executes.  Try this:

```
start /wait myapp.exe
```

(That's how you would do it in an interactive command shell.)

If that doesn't work, you may have to consult the author of the parent process for advice.